# how to understand column types from sql file?

Tags: postgresql

I am not good at column types as I understand. From another country with another system they just send me a sql file and they claim that there is an image on that sql file. I guess it is byte array, however I couldnt insert it into PostgreSQL. When I try to insert it says:

```
LINE 1: ...ES ('00246c4e-1bc8-4dde-bb89-e9dee69990d5', '0', 0xffa0ffa40...
                                                             ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "xffa0f
```

Could you please help me to create related table with its column properties?

I know that it is not good question, however here is starting of sql file;

```
INSERT INTO `fps` VALUES ('00246c4e-1bc8-4dde-bb89-e9dee69990d5', '0', 0xffa0ffa4003a0907000932d325cd000ae0f3199a010a41eff19a010b8e2......
```

What is the type of 0xffa0ff....?

Comment: This is a HEX string. The column's type should be kind of BLOB

Comment: Don't include products(tags) which are not involved in problem...

Comment: I see, what about first and second column types?

Comment: There is `bytea` data type in postgres that is supposed to store binary data. See examples of `decode()` function in postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'00246c4e-1bc8-4dde-bb89-e9dee69990d5'` is a [`UUID`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-uuid.html).

`'0'` is just a character string. There are [a few different string types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html) to choose from. However, if all of these values are integers, you may want to create the column as an [`INTEGER`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html) instead.

`0xff...` is a [hex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) string, though not in a format that Postgres will recognise. You can store this data in a [`bytea`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html) column, but in order for the `INSERT` to succeed, you will need to modify the script, replacing, for example,

```
0xab...ef
```

with

```
'\xab...ef'
```

Comment: When I change value as you describe, it says ERROR:  malformed array literal: "\xffa0ffa4003a0............"

Comment: Did you declare your column as `bytea`, or `bytea[]`?

Comment: Yes you are right. I should do it bytea not bytea[].